# EF VAT table Calculating Vat rate on specific date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an MVC3 application in C# using Entity Framework. I have a VAT rates table which has VAT rate, Start Date, End date fields.
Start Date and end date can be null to indicate that either this is a historical rate or an ongoing rate. What I am trying to figure out, is how do create a single query that takes these nulls into account to give me the vat rate when I pass in a single date. 
(nb example shows uk date format dd/mm/yyyy

```
+--------------+-------------+----------+
| Start Date   | End Date    | Vat rate |
+--------------+-------------+----------+
| Null         | 01/01/2011  | 19       |
+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 02/01/2011   | 08/08/2011  | 20       |
+--------------+-------------+----------+
| 09/08/2011   | Null        | 21       |
+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: This would be messy and I'd probably get it wrong if I tried... but why not just set StartDate = minimum SQL date value, EndDate = maximum SQL date value and avoid the evil nulls altogether?  You could also just have a start date,  you don't need an end date,  and then your data can never be inconsistent - it can be wrong - but not inconsistent. Except I suppose if you have 2 start dates the same but that's easy to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF, you can do something like this:

```
DateTime first = DateTime.Parse("01-01-1900");
DateTime last = DateTime.Parse("01-01-2100");
var rate = db.VatRates.Where(
    vr => input > (vr.StartDate ?? first) && input < (vr.EndDate ?? last)).First().Rate;
```

According to comment below, without EndDate column try this:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("01-01-1900");
var rate = db.VatRates.Where(vr => input > (vr.StartDate ?? start))
    .OrderByDescending(vr => vr.StartDate).First().Rate;
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Yes I am usign EF, I thought I had it but I still cannot get the result I need. I have removed the end date column so the table looks as before, but without this column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pass in @Date

```
SELECT      VATRate 
FROM        VATRateTable
WHERE       @Date
BETWEEN     ISNULL(StartDate, '1900-01-01') AND ISNULL(EndDate, '2100-01-01')
```